# Include assets into package's blade view - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I'm creating a package using Laravel 5.4. I need to include some assets(js, CSS & images) in the blade template. How can I achieve that?

I have tried asset(), but it is not working.

Here is the folder structure of my package:

```
root
  --package
     -- vendor_name
        -- package_name
           -- src
              -- assets
                 -- js
                    -- login.js
                 --css
                    -- login.css
              -- views
                 -- login.blade.php
```

Is it something possible without publishing them into the public folder?

Thanks

Comment: `asset()` provides a path to the public directory of your laravel project. Your files seems to be in vendor dir. Is that right?

Comment: It is not possible the way you do. The browser will try to load the CSS references and Javascript sources using HTTP requests and to the only folder open to HTTP requests for Laravel is the public folder. As you are talking about a package and many of the installations follow good practices, you have to move them to public folder as the answers already suggests.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.4 you can use mix function it is much better if you want to use versions

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/login.js') }}"></script>
```

see Compiling Assets (Laravel Mix)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

```
mix.js(['resources/assets/js/app.js'], 'public/js')
        .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
        .styles([
            'node_modules/animate.css/animate.css',
            'node_modules/icheck/skins/flat/green.css',
            'node_modules/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css',
            'node_modules/gentelella/vendors/switchery/dist/switchery.min.css',
            'node_modules/ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css',
            'node_modules/ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css',
            'node_modules/gentelella/vendors/google-code-prettify/bin/prettify.min.css',
            //bootstrap modal carousel.js
            //'node_module/bootstrap-modal-carousel/dist/css/bootstrap-modal-carousel.css',
            'node_modules/gentelella/build/css/custom.css',
            'resources/assets/css/custom.css'
        ], 'public/css/custom.css')
        .copy('node_modules/gentelella/vendors/switchery/dist/switchery.min.js', 'public/js/switchery.min.js')
        .copy('node_modules/gentelella/vendors/switchery/dist/switchery.min.css', 'public/css/switchery.min.css')
        .copy('resources/assets/images', 'public/images')
        .copy('node_modules/ion-rangeslider/img', 'public/img')
        .copy('node_modules/icheck/skins/flat/green.png', 'public/css')
        .copy('node_modules/icheck/skins/flat/green@2x.png', 'public/css').version();
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't get my question.

Comment: No, you can put what you need in webpack.mix.js then compile it, I understand you but I mean this is better. look at updated code

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new disk in your `config/filesystem.php` that point to that folder.

```
'package' => [
            'driver' => 'package',
            'root' => base_path('package'),
        ],
```

**in blade**

`{{ Storage::disk('package')->url('vendor_name/package_name/src/assets/js/login.js') }}`

**custom directory for the views**

to edit this you have to go in `config/view.php` and add your paths `base_path('package/vendor_name/package_name/src/views')` for each package.

```
'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
        base_path('package/vendor_name/package_name/src/views'),
    ],
```